# Regex - How to check if string only contains specific characters instead of all?

Tags: c#, regex

Here is my code:

```
string rejon = textBox.Text.Trim();

if ((!Regex.IsMatch(rejon, @"^[a-zA-Z]\d{3}$")))
{
    MessageBox.Show("Error. Please, try again!", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, 
    MessageBoxIcon.Error);

    textBox.Clear();
    textBox.Focus();
    return false;
}
```

Instead of all alphabetic character [a-zA-Z] I want just letters "R" and "S". Is it possible to do in regex? I know that I can substring this and than put another validation, but I am asking can I do this with regex?

Comment: Sure, just use [RS] instead of [a-zA-Z]

Comment: You want to check if the string has R or (and) S only? E.g. "RRR", "RSR", "SSS"?

Comment: @RahulHendawe As far as I know you do not need the `-` in that expression

Comment: @TheLethalCoder: You are right, Thanks for correcting me.

Comment: You could also keep things simple and just do:
if (rejon[0] != 'R' && rejon[0] != 'S')

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll have to change `[a-zA-Z]` to `[RS]` to check if only "R"s and "S"s are in the string.

Comment: By only making this change it will only check if the string starts with R or S

Comment: Isn't this what OP wants? *Instead of all [...] just letters "R" and "S".*

Comment: I don't know I find the wording a bit unclear, just thought I'd mention it

Comment: @TheLethalCoder You're right, it isn't clear out of the question. As far as I understood this is what he was searching for.

Comment: I am sorry if I posted unclear question, by only making this change i will only check if the string starts with R or S and that is exactly what I need.

Answer (score 1):

You just have to change [a-zA-Z] to [RS] to check just letters "R" and "S".

Answer (score 1):

It is better to use `/^[RS]+$/i` or `/^[RSrs]+$/` to match an input string of ASCII alphabets.